# I want to dynamically list certain objects for a certain radius using yandex

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, yandex-maps, yandex-api

```
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
center: \[55.73, 37.75\],
zoom: 12
}, {
searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
}),
cafe, metro;

    function findClosestObjects () {
        cafe.getClosestTo(metro.get(0)).balloon.open();
        
        // Opening the balloon of the cafe that is closest to the click.
        myMap.events.add('click', function (event) {
            cafe.getClosestTo(event.get('coords')).balloon.open();
        });
    }
    cafe = ymaps.geoQuery({
        type: 'FeatureCollection',
        features: [{
                type: 'Feature',
                properties: {
                    balloonContent: 'Darth Vader coffee shop - we have cookies!'
                },
                geometry: {
                    type: 'Point',
                    coordinates: [55.724166, 37.545849]
                }
            }, {
                type: 'Feature',
                properties: {
                    balloonContent: 'Gollum cafe - lovely cakes.'
                },
                geometry: {
                    type: 'Point',
                    coordinates: [55.717495, 37.567886]
                }
            }, {
                type: 'Feature',
                properties: {
                    balloonContent: 'Brick cafe: strong coffee for strong guys.'
                },
                geometry: {
                    type: 'Point',
                    coordinates: [55.7210180,37.631057]
                }
            }
        ]
    }).addToMap(myMap);
    
    metro = ymaps.geoQuery(ymaps.geocode([55.744828, 37.603423], {kind: 'metro'}))
        .then(findClosestObjects);

}
```

I have reviewed Yandex's api documentation for javascript. I need a structure or alternative similar to the nearbySearch method for Places Api in Google Maps.

I searched for a method similar to the nearbySearch method used for Google maps and at the end of the day I found the above example with constant variables.

Comment: What prevents you from using the Google Maps API?